# Getting string attribute from a shapefile with GDAL Feature.GetFieldAsString(name) returns incomplete value

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr

I read a shapefile (zipped) with GDAL library in C#. Shapefile contains .cpg file with "UTF-8" encoding specified.

When I call `Feature.GetFieldAsString(attributeName)` some of the attribute values get trimmed at the end, and some have broken symbols.

Converting shapefile to GeoJSON with ogr2ogr makes a GeoJSON file with all attributes as they are supposed to be.

For example, value returned by `GetFieldAsString` is "**\"Тер�**", when the real value, also seen in geojson is "**\"Терем+\"**".

This doesn't seem to be an issue with encoding, for the beginning of the string is read correctly. But I have no clue where to look for the solution for this issue.

Comment: I believe the encoding does have a role. Beginning of your string is pure ASCII characters and they do not expose the problem.

Comment: Only " and + characters in the string are ASCII, the rest are cyrillic characters.

Comment: Test data and C# code that shows the problem would be appreciated. Python code equivalent might be even better because I guess there are not so many C# programmers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've debugged the issue thoroughly and found the route cause. GDAL library itself returns correct value as a pointer to the attribute string, but the C# bindings, generated by SWIG, have some strange code that truncates valid UTF-8 string into a broken one.

It may be because we use an outdated GDAL.Core Nuget package, or the issue is in the binding itself. Still looking for a nice solution, but at least now I have somewhere to start from.

Comment: Please if you find a bug in GDAL create a ticket in GitHub with test data that can be used for re-producing the issue.